# Reading long string from socket in Android issue

Tags: android, inputstream, serversocket

I am getting long string data from server via socket and there is reading issue .

Data is around 10 MB .

```
private String createSocketConnection() throws IOException {
            String result = "";

        {
            String host = ServiceUrlManager.socketIP;
            int port = ServiceUrlManager.socketPort;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            socket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
            Log.d(TAG, ":::::Socket Connection " + socket.isConnected());
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(createMSG());  
            dataOutputStream.write(sockecData);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

        //Read data from server connection
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();


            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            for(int s; (s=inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1; )
            {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, s);

            }

            String data = ISOUtil.hexString(baos.toByteArray());
            result = data.substring(0, baos.toByteArray().length); // response message
            Log.d(TAG, "::::Response " + result);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you do that from the main thread or in an other `Thread` ?

Comment: `and there is reading issue .`. Which issue exactly? Exceptions? Please post the logcat.

Comment: Please dont use a ByteArrayOutputStream. You are using soo much memory then. Better write the bytes to a FileOutputStream.

Comment: @Raphael i m using separate thread .

Comment: @greeapps i am not getting any exception when loop is going to complete then it is not going on next line infinitely loading. it is loading only some data and rest are breaking in string.

Comment: Unclear how many data you can download from the 10 MB. Please give exact amount of bytes. Is it always the same? It is unclear what you mean with 'rest is breaking in string'. Now do away with the ByteArrayOutputStream for a test.

Comment: @greenapps  incomplete string are able to fetch in loop.When 2 times loop executes and fetch buffer data third time it is hanged ....NO any exception.. I mean to say 2kB data read easily then not able to read. I tried to increase buffer size as well .

Answer (score 0):

```
  BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(inputStream.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    while(br.readLine!=null){
        sb.append(br.readLine());
    }
```